# Google Cloud write permission's

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bitnami

I've just created a django instance on Google Cloud using bitnami and below is the result of how I tried to git clone a repo and later found out the folder seems to have no write permissions.

What I want to do after getting write access is git clone the repo then replace it with the default Project folder. If someone knows of a tutorial on this or a guide too it would help too, if you only need to edit a few files or use a pre-made bitnami code.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitnami documentation usually assumes that server console commands are executed under the `bitnami` user account. However, when connecting through a browser SSH console, you may be logged in under a different user account. To switch to the bitnami user account, use the command

```
sudo su - bitnami
```

From what I see in your screenshot, it seems that you are using the browser SSH console with the user `muiruri_samuel`. Once you run the above command, your issue should be solved.